# Between Subject Covariates and Within Subject Variables in Longitudinal - Long format data

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I have a longitudinal nested and crossed design dataset with both between-subject covariates and within-subject variables. My study design is below in figure 1.

[image]

As shown, the between-subject variable is measured only once that the very beginning of study.
The first within-subject variable (WS1) is measured three times throughout the study.
The second within-subject variable (WS2) is measured three times during each subsession. This is the crossed variable.

In pose, the study would be:
Collect Between-Subject variable
Collect WS1 followed by WS2 three times
repeat step 2 two more times

Due to the nested design, I need to run a hierarchical linear model. As such, the data is required to be in long-form. However, when done this way we break the assumption of a 1-1 input-output. The data setup example is shown below:

[image]

As shown, The participant is nested into their group, and the session and sub-session are crossed with each participant.

BW-1 is recorded only once, but due to the transition to long-form, it is artificially replicated 9 times. The same is seen for WS-1 where it is artificially replicated 3 times. However, WS-2 is repeated but not artificially replicated.

My hypothetical model for this would be predicting WS-1 with WS-2 and BW-1 where Z(Team) is my multilevel modifier:

WS-1 ~ B1(BS-1) + Session*SubSession*B2(WS-2) + Z(Team)

Under this assumption, however, the following issue occurs:

[image]

Which translates to:

[image]

So BW-1 is the same value that corresponds to three of the same output values. But, there is no interest in analyzing the output of the same value three times.

Under my current understanding, this is incorrect. If so, could you explain or provide a source as to how to correctly apply the regression equation?